# How to assign Hotkey for a shortcut which is deployed through Wix

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.5

I am trying to assign an HotKey (Ctrl+Alt+S) for a shortcut I deploy on Windows Desktop using Wix. Below is how I tried to assign the value. However the compiler says that the Hotkey value has to be a integer value.

```
<Shortcut Id="ToolsShortcut" WorkingDirectory="System" Icon="icon.vbs"      Directory="DesktopFolder" Hotkey="Ctrl+Alt+S" Description="Shortcut to Launch the Tools Framework" Name="Tools.lnk" Advertise="yes">
```

Please could anyone tell me how to determine the equivalent integer value for Ctrl+Alt+S

Currently I know that I have to somehow combine the Hex equivalent for the individual keys to create the Hotkey.

Here's a link to [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927178.aspx).

Below are the Hex values for the individual keys:

```
Ctrl: 11
Alt: 12
S: 53
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **1619** for Ctrl + Alt + S. It's a combination of the virtual key code and modifier flags. They are not really documented, but you can determine them through experiments.

To get this number I used a [Hot Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775234%28VS.85%29.aspx) control and [HKM_GETHOTKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775235%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: thanks. i tried assigning 1619 to the Hotkey attribute but it did not work. Please could you let me know how did you come up with that number.

Comment: 1619 does work. apparently hotkeys was disabled by default on my windows XP OS. i had to enable it by making an entry in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you find it or not, beware of the warning placed in the wix.chm:

> Authors of installation packages are
>   generally recommend not to set this
>   option, because this can add duplicate
>   hotkeys to a users desktop. In
>   addition, the practice of assigning
>   hotkeys to shortcuts can be
>   problematic for users using hotkeys
>   for accessibility.

Comment: thanks. i read that before but its part of the requirement for the project i am working on.